# display series of images with next button

Tags: java

How can I display a series of images one by one every time the user clicks the next button?
I have few images stored in array. I used button next to go from image to image. How to programme the button? I used action listener but I just don't know how to get back to the array.

Comment: Any particular language? Framework? Any other info that gives us a shred of an idea of what you need help with?

Comment: I would program the button to go to the next image.

Comment: I used java. I dont know how to write for the action listener for button. e.g 
if (e.getSource()==buttonNext) {
...how to program to the next image?

Comment: Maybe you should post what you have so far.

Comment: Thanks everyone...
I have another problem...I dont know how to display it on JPanel.
I add the code segment on Answers.

Comment: Hi, I have successfuly display image/drawing on JPanel...however its only display one drawing..in fact I have few images/drawing tht i put in array. everytime i click on button, it doesnt change the drawing? Please helpp...:-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm being lazy here by not writing the entire code, but here goes anyway.

```
class whatEver implements ActionListener{
    JButton btnNext = new JButton();
    static int fileNumber = 0;
    static int totalFiles;

   void functionLoadInterface ()  //Function with
    {
        btnNext.addActionListener(this); 
        //Initialize array ImageArray with file paths.
    }

   public void cycleImage()
    { 
         String file = ImageArray[fileNumber%totalFiles];
         //Code to load the image wherever follows
    } 

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
         filenumber++;
         this.cycleImage();
    }
```